# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 46: Installing Python packages (pip, nose etc.) on Windows

Tags: python, installation, pip, nose

I am learning Python using Zed Shaw's "Learn Python the Hard Way" on Windows using PowerShell. I am in [Exercise 46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) where you set up a skelton project. I downloaded [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), [nose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/), and [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and I installed them by typing:

> `python <filename>.py install`

However, probably because they were not installed where they were supposed to, when I try

> `nosetests`

I get errors saying "The term 'nosetests' is not recognized as the name of a cmdelt, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the mae, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.... CommandNotFoundException".

I have been going through the exercises fine, so I thought that the path was correct but do you have to change it now? Right now, I have the packages under the directory where I have my skelton (..project/skelton). I am sorry for a real-beginner question but if anybody could help me with this, I highly appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but the answer was in the book. Type this into powershell, hope it works for you too.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
```

Comment: And restart the computer to make the changes effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> ```
> // make sure you have pip and virtualenv installed
> cd project
> // create a virtual environment
> virtualenv venv --distribute
> // activate the virtual environment 
> // I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is correct way on windows
> venv\Scripts\activate.bat
> // install nose
> pip install nose
> ```

You should now be able to run nosetests as long as your virtualenv is activated.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. When you say you have pip and vitualenv installed, where should they be installed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear on that. You can install virtualenv and pip with easy_install. You can get easy_install from here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools.

Comment: Sorry my reply was not clear either! I mean when you download easy_install from the web site you told me, where in my PC should it be installed? Sorry for a really basic question!

Comment: Just download and run the .exe installer, or stick to the instructions if you're running 64bit. After that be sure to add the Python Scripts subdirectory to your PATH.

Comment: I could not complete it because it gave me an error saying it already exists. I could not change where it should be installed or exit... I have no idea what is going wrong... :(

Comment: After all, I was missing a semicolon to add new PATHs! Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is late for your question, but this may help others that will experience the same issue that we've experienced. I've got mine working doing the ff. steps:

(Assuming that you've downloaded all packages as discussed in the book):

1. pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py (save that as python file)
2. distribute from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute
3. nose from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/
4. virtualenv from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Follow this to install all:

- Run Windows Powershell as Administrator
- cd C:\Path_Where_You_Downloaded_get-pip.py
- Install pip by using the command 'python get-pip.py'
- Run Command Prompt as Administrator
- cd to location of Python27 scripts (in my case C:\Python27\Scripts)
- Try to update pip using the command 'pip install --upgrade pip'
- Install Nose by using this command 'pip install C:\Path_Where_You_downloaded_nose'
- Install distribute using command 'pip install distribute'

Hope this helps!