# Nosetests on Windows Powershell do nothing?

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, nosetests

I followed Zed Shaw's instruction in his book, "Learn Python the Hard Way 3rd Edition"

On my Windows Powershell, nosetests do nothing, I just saw the cursor blinked until the end of the world. Why is that? How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi, does it work in cmd ? Should it open an interactive shell ? Also, see if this helps in any way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511809/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-46-installing-python-packages-pip-nose-etc

Comment: Darn I'm so silly hahaha, I ran nosetests on the wrong directory. Thank you for your answer :) It takes time to run, my Avast will do scan, maybe 15-20 seconds.

Comment: This is still an important question. Nothing happens when I run `nosetests` through a docker container when using the PowerShell terminal, but when I use `cmd` it works. the `--exe` flag doesn't make a difference and chmod -x does nothing when using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

According to the author, the cause of the issue was ... trivial :

> Darn I'm so silly hahaha, I ran nosetests on the wrong directory. Thank you for your answer :) It takes time to run, my Avast will do scan, maybe 15-20 seconds. – mdominic 1 hour ago